# How to import module to Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

```py
import myModule as myModule
```

with this code works import and I can make my doc

```py
import myPackage.myModule as myModule
```

with this I get

> "No module named myPackage.myModule"

Doesn't matter if this file exist in root directory or in myPackage directory.

In RST-File I have not mentioned about myModule, I want to document other file that just import this module.

Answer (score 10):

Sphinx needs to be able to import your code, to generate documentation for classes and functions. You probably need to add your project's root folder to sys.path in Sphinx. You can do this from the Sphinx `conf.py` file:

```
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))
```

Replace `'..'` with the relative path to the project root.

Comment: what if my project root is two directories up, rather than just one?

Comment: @Dave then replace '..' with '../..'