# Sphinx doc struggling with import typing

Tags: python, python-sphinx, python-typing

today, I setup a simple sphinx job for my python project. When I hit "make html" it crashes with the following messages:

> WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'myname.mymodule'; the following exception was raised:
>   cannot import name 'MyClass'

I deleted line by line and now, if I remove

```
from typing import Tuple
```

in front of myname.mymodule, sphinx does the docu with errors (can't find Tuple) of course.

I can easily attach the log, referenced by sphinx, but the only intresting in it is this:

> while not self.fetch_token().match([OP, '='], NEWLINE, COMMENT):
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'match'

Does sphinx has a problem with typing? Or is there something broken with my imports ?

Comment: Are you importing other modules besides `typing`?

Comment: Which Sphinx and which Python version are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/9003734/2214933

Comment: @Alfred I importing a few of my own project modules. besides my own code, i only use a few like shutil, os, datetime, unittest, sqlalchemy

Comment: @9769953 I'am using Sphinx 1.7.6 and python 3.6.5

Comment: @StevePiercy mh as far as i see, it's no duplicate. i set this path  and my own modules are no problem for sphinx

Comment: @DonCarlos please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including project file structure and how you set your $PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug. 
It had nothing todo with the imports. That was a sideeffect.

The code in a class used an Exception type, which was defined in the same file but *after* the class.

I moved the Exception Class in front of the file and now, sphinx is working fine.